# Как создать динамическое имя переменной?

Tags: php

Имеется функция getp(), которая возвращает строку.

```
$p1 = getp();           //p1 = 'Wd
$p2 = getp();           //p2 = Xr'

//нужно из $р1 и $р2  создать переменную $р3, $WdXr
//чтобы в коде можно было обращаться к $WdXr
```

Как такое сделать?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php или http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php сделают то, что вам надо...если вы про php, ведь вы не указали язык

Comment: offtop: название темы напомнило "каштом от вована" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен.

```
$p1 = 'Wd';
$p2 = 'Xr';
$p3 = "$p1$p2";
$$p3 = 'test';
echo $WdXr;
```

благодарю  за ссылки

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде такого:

```
$p1 = getp();           //p1 = 'Wd
$p2 = getp();           //p2 = Xr'
$p3 = $p1 . $p2;
```

Вызов в коде переменной, название которой храним в `$p3`:

`$$p3`